# Cómo devolver una fecha formateada?

Tags: laravel

cómo debería tomar el mes y día solamente desde una consulta? Lo hice de esta manera pero me devuelve el error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be
>   string, array given (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\netuz\resources\views\home.blade.php)

El código:

```
$fechas = Parte::select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(fecha,"%m-%d") as fecha'))
    ->skip(0)->take(3)->get()->toArray();

return view('home', [
    'fechas' => $fechas
]);
```

En la vista tengo un script JS que la utiliza:

```
var fechas = {{ $fechas }};
var barChartData = {
    labels: fechas,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Click',
        backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        data: data_click
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que estás utilizando la variable "fechas" como un string, cuando en realidad le estás pasando un vector.

O sea, deberías cambiar esto:

```
return view('home', [
    'fechas' => $fechas
]);
```

y esto del blade:

```
var fechas = {{ $fechas }};
```

Por esto:

```
return view('home', [
    'fechas' => json_encode($fechas, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES )
]);
```

Y esto en la vista

```
var fechas = {!! $fechas !!};
```

Con este cambio le pasamos al blade un string con el contenido de un vector de JS, y en la vista lo mostramos sin formatearlo.

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: ahí agregué lo que tengo en la vista.

Comment: Ya cambié la respuesta para usar tu código como ejemplo.